# How to use an ActionListener to check for an instance of and adding to an arrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, event-handling, actionlistener

I have created an GUI that accepts the following fields (name, street, city, state, zip, account number). In addition you are able to choose between 3 customer Types from a panel and finally a course from a drop down course ComboBox.

When the user types in the above information and clicks “SUBMIT”, the program will create the customer if they don’t exist and put them on the customer list, find the selected course on the course list and ask the user if they wish to enroll in the course with a confirmation pop up dialog.  If the user selects YES, the course is added to that customer’s course list, the fields are cleared, the cursor is placed in the name field, and another entry is possible.  If the customer already exits, a new customer is not created, but the course is added to that customer’s course list.
When the user clicks “FINISH”, the program writes to the prompt each customer and their course list, displays the dialog box of invoices, then exits.
Anonymous actionListeners are used. I need to have a method for `clearFields`, `addCourse` that accepts the customer name and the course title, `addCustomer` that uses the data in the fields to create customers and add them to the customer list, `readCourses` that reads `courses.txt`, creates the courses and adds them to the course list, and populates the string array used for the drop down box selections, and `generateInvoice`. This is as far as I have got.

```
submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
          if (confirm())
    {
                customerList.add(new Customer(nameField.getText(),new Address(streetField.getText(), cityField.getText(), stateField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(zipField.getText())), Integer.parseInt(accountNumberField.getText())));
            }

    clearFields();            
        }
    });

    finishButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            for(Customer c: customerList)
                System.out.println(c.toString());

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    add(nameLabel);
    add(nameField);  
    add(streetLabel);
    add(streetField);
    add(cityLabel);
    add(cityField);  
    add(stateLabel);
    add(stateField);
    add(zipLabel);
    add(zipField); 
    add(accountNumberLabel);
    add(accountNumberField);

    add(customerLabel);
    add(myPanel);

    add(courseLabel);
    add(courseBox);

    add(submitLabel);
    add(submitButton);

    add(finishLabel);
    add(finishButton);
}   

public static void main(String args[])
{
    CourseGUI g = new CourseGUI();

    g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    g.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    g.setSize(650,350);

    g.setVisible(true);
}   

public void clearFields()
{
    nameField.setText("");
    streetField.setText("");
    cityField.setText("");
    stateField.setText("");
    zipField.setText("");
    accountNumberField.setText("");
    myGroup.clearSelection();
courseBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

nameField.requestFocus();
}

public String getCourse()
{
   return courses[courseBox.getSelectedIndex()];        
}

public String getClassification()
{
if (studentButton.isSelected())
return studentButton.getText();
else if (facultyButton.isSelected())
return facultyButton.getText();
else 
return governmentButton.getText();
}

public boolean confirm()
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

int result;

String message;

message = String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %d %d", nameField.getText(), streetField.getText(), cityField.getText(), stateField.getText(), zipField.getText(), accountNumberField.getText());

result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, message);

if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        return true;
return false;
}
```

**What I need help with is the coding inside my submitButton. `addActionListener`. How would I check to see if a customer already exist and if not then add them to the `customerList`.
Assume all other classes and arrayList needed are already created.**

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to first decide, functionally, when you consider that a customer entered by the user already exists in the list. In short: what makes a customer equal to another customer.

Are they equal if they share the same name? Or if theyr share the same name and the same account number? Or the same name and the same address?

Depending on that, override the methods `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()` in the Customer class. Make sure to read the javadoc of those methods to understand their contract.

And finally, in the action listener, test that the list doesn't contain the Customer already (using the `contains()` method) before adding it to the list.